# Script to change the user input file path for the files located in different folders

Tags: shell, ksh

I have a following script,

```
#!/bin/ksh 
#***********************************************************
echo "Enter Local Drive path LOCALPATH:"
read LOCALPATH
echo "Enter NA R Drive NAPATH:"
read NAPATH![enter image description here][1]
find ./ -type f | xargs sed -i "s|$LOCALPATH|$NAPATH|g" Run.param
#
```

which is working fine in a single directory & changing the contents of Run.param file

Comment: Your script doesn't only change `Run.param`. It changes all the files in the folder, because `xargs` adds all the filenames that `find` lists to the end of the command line.

Comment: `find` automatically goes into subdirectories. So if you run the script from the parent directory, it should update all the files in all the subdirectories.

Comment: Change `find ./` to `find ${1-.}` and pass a parameter on the command line.

Comment: maybe I'm missing something, but if the goal is to edit all `Run.param` files, why not `find ./ -name Run.param | xargs ...` ? Good luck to all.

Comment: Thanks @ Barmar for clarification on Find command.
Even in my base script I am getting a error message as sed: can't read PedFlow_Run.param: No such file or directory. So  I need to correct this first before implementing the changes what you all suggested. Thanks a lot for the quick reply.

Comment: Thanks @ William & Shellter...will let yo once I am successful.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are asking about the directory NAPATH:

change

```
find ./ -type f | xargs sed -i "s|$LOCALPATH|$NAPATH|g" Run.param
```

to

```
OUTER = $NAPATH/..

for d in $OUTER/*; do
    find ./ -type f | xargs sed -i "s|$LOCALPATH|$d|g" Run.param
done
```

if Run.param is located in NAPATH, use:

```
OUTER = $NAPATH/..

for d in $OUTER/*; do
    find ./ -type f | xargs sed -i "s|$LOCALPATH|$d|g" $NAPATH/Run.param
done
```

Comment: Thanks Ganesh, My I have a problem now , my script is not able to read the Run.param file & I am getting a error message as " sed: can't read PedFlow_Run.param: No such file or directory " , pls help me how to solve.

Comment: thanks Ganesh, my base script is working now...( had a permission problems.....simple mistake..)

Comment: Hi Ganesh..continuation to this I have added another post  " "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718930/unix-script-for-multiple-job-creations-submissions " Please help me with your valuable suggestions. Thanks in advance.